# getting nearest Metro station location in google map in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been working on an app where I have successfully shown my location and map. Now I am trying to find the location of nearest `metro station` from my current position and display its properties , names etc.

I have tried

> google

but can't find any solution. If anyone can help with any tutorial or anything related, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)
You can search by cordinates and filter to show only certain objects.